ls / hangs indefinitely
This problem started just today:
I tried opening nautilus, and it didn't open.
Then I opened ranger, and it didn't open.
Dolphin also didn't work.
Since I needed to do something on /etc, I just opened the terminal and typed cd / <TAB> to trigger the autocompletion.
That also hanged.
So I tried ls / and it just hanged.
If I start the system in recovery mode, and enter root shell, I can ls / , but as soon as I boot into normal mode, or even just "resume" boot from recovery, ls / doesn't work.
My fstab:
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/69449272-f753-4a04-ab50-ad56d91cca2d / ext4 defaults 0 1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/7973-BDE9 /boot/efi vfat defaults 0 1
/swap.img       none    swap    sw      0       0
UUID=eec53adb-9e10-4812-b79f-a01eca782afe /media/jio/A auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
UUID=44c589ed-0f52-4abc-bd5b-6b67c4096312 /media/jio/B auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0

Edit: It suddenly started working again, and I have no idea why.
Edit 2: It stopped working again.

Does a cd to /etc work?

@quill yes, and I can ls in /etc

OK, then things such as /var/log are probably available.  1) what is in your /etc/fstab file (post it here)  2) try an ls command on /media - which may fail.  3) did you add anything at the root ie. / level ?

@quill ls /media works, I'll update the question with my fstab. And no, I did not add anything to the root level, BUT suddenly it started working again.

@user68186 I want to close it, because it already solved itself (although I don't know why or how). How do I manually close it?

Do we really want to close it or, modify it to cover other instances?  I've had hang conditions where a mounted drive was off line. I can make it happen any time.  I have several connected systems, some of which I power off during the night.  If I attempt something like ls when those systems are powered off without first unmounting, I'll get a hang condition until they are powered on the next day.  Perhaps others are not aware they could get a similar result?

Actually, it not a true hang - it's a very LONG wait until something internal times out.

@quill Please ask a new question with specifics of your problem.

It's not really a question for me.  If I asked it as a question someone would probably mark it as a dumb question that shouldn't have been asked and down vote it especially since it's not an issue.

@quill I'm not sure if it's a mounted drive issue. I have 5 drives: 1 with ubuntu, 1 with artix, 1 with windows, and 2 storage units. The storage units are mounted on boot (or maybe before, because my grub uses an image stored in one of these volumes as wallpaper). The only thing I had changed was the secure boot option in my bios, but I changed it back and the problem persisted. Honestly, I have no idea what happened, because now it works as it should.

I'd check the disk's health using smartctl (mechanical drive / smartctl -a /dev/whatever) or perform a non-destructive badblocks run (SSD / badblocks -nsv /dev/whatever from a Live ISO).

All of the commands you are using are hanging when it tries to access your / partition, which means that the / partition is likely the culprit.
When you enter a recovery shell, the / partition is typically mounted read only. To help diagnose this issue, the first thing to do is to go back to your recovery shell and type:
mount -o rw /

That should attempt to switch your partition over to rw mode. If this fixed your issue, then it isn't the physical media. If it fails then the error message should hopefully be descriptive enough to lead you to your next step.
If mount -o rw did work as expected, then it is something later in the boot sequence that is causing an issue. Typically the next thing to do is to check, is it another partition causing an issue? Do you have an encrypted home directory? Does mount -o rw /home give you an error?
If none of that works, logs are your friend. dmesg can provide kernel messages, which might contain more information. In the same vein, if /var is mounted rw, /var/log/syslog is also a good place to look.

it only says "/dev/nvme0n1p2 is already mounted on /. dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call."

You need remount if the filesystem is already mounted: mount -o remount,rw /
